# Magento 2 : How to get Product url in custom page

Tags: magento-2.1.7

In my block I have provide a function to fetch product details from product Id. Code in block file

```
 public function getProductById($pid) 
{ 
    $product = $this->_productRepository->getById($pid);
    return $product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($product);
}
```

And in .phtml file I have provided

```
  $returnProdId = $block->getProductById($returnItems['products']);
  print_r($returnProdId);
```

But the result is not as expected.Result which I am getting is 
  http://localhost/magento2/index.php/catalog/product/view/id/1420/s/iris-workout-top-xs-red/

Please help on the same.

Answer (score 5):

Can you please try by replacing below

```
 public function getProductById($pid) 
{ 
    $product = $this->_productRepository->getById($pid);
    return $product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($product);
}
```

With

```
public function getProductById($pid) 
    { 
        $product = $this->_productRepository->getById($pid);
        return $product->getProductUrl();
    }
```